# Linq: Calculate difference between two entries based on condition (lookahead)

Tags: c#, linq

A database contains log entries for errors with specific codes for a device. An error is active if the code is non 0 and inactive if it is 0. Only one error at a time can be active, so there is a time frame where the device is "in error" and "not in error"; but many other error codes can be posted at the same time (which is not relevant for the device error state, which is of interest here).

I want to calculate the times that the device is "in error". Unfortunately, we cannot assume that the errors are always alternating `(101, 0, 200, 0, 302, 0)` but may be more chaotic `(3, 101, 0, 20, 202, 10, 0, 0, 102, ...)`. Here, the error time would be counted from the first non zero error code until the first 0 each time, so the dfference of time between the first non zero occurence until the first zero occurence, then again from the first non zero etc.

In other words:

```
timeStamp    code
100          101
200          0
300          500
350          501
400          0

--> Total Error Time = 200 ((200 - 100) + (400 - 300))
```

In a loop, that would be a task of something like this:

```cs
totalErrorTime = 0;
previousError = errors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code != 0);

errors.forEach(error => {
    if (previousError.code == 0 && error.code != 0)
        // Set first encountered non zero error code
        previousError = error;
    if (error.code == 0) {
        // Encountered 0 error code, calculate difference
        totalErrorTime += error.timeStamp - previousError.timeStamp;
        // Set previous error to this error for lookahead
        previousError = error;
    }
}
```

But I wonder how I could perform a similar operation in Linq. So far, I was thinking of something like this:

```cs
var skippedErrors = errors;

result = errors
      .Zip(skippedErrors.Skip(1).SkipWhile(x => x.code != 0), (a, b) => new
           {
                 errorTime = b.timeStamp - a.timeStamp
           })
      .Select(x => new ErrorTimeResult(x.Sum(y => y.errorTime))));
```

However, I do not think that the `SkipWhile()` portion is safe.

How can I do these kinds of "lookaheads" in Linq? I think that `Zip()` is the right approach, but how can I ensure to only count each "error phase" once? Thank you.

Comment: Is not easier and performant do this at database level?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to normalize the values, then do a subquery followed by a group by to get the data, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            var l = (new[]
            {
                new{ TimeStamp = 100, Code = 0 },
                new{ TimeStamp = 200, Code = 2 },
                new{ TimeStamp = 300, Code = 3 },
                new{ TimeStamp = 400, Code = 0 },
                new{ TimeStamp = 520, Code = 34 },
                new{ TimeStamp = 50, Code = 2 },
                new{ TimeStamp = 500, Code = 0 }
            }).ToList();

            l = l.OrderBy(a => a.TimeStamp).ToList();
            var err = l.OrderBy(a => a.TimeStamp).Select(a => new
            {
                code = a.Code == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                a.TimeStamp,
                last = l.FirstOrDefault(b => b.TimeStamp > a.TimeStamp)?.Code == 0 ? 0 : 1,
                lastTimestamp = l.FirstOrDefault(b => b.TimeStamp > a.TimeStamp)?.TimeStamp
            }).GroupBy(a => new {a.code, a.last},
                a => new {a.TimeStamp, a.lastTimestamp }, 
                (key, g) => new  {
                        key.code, key.last, timestamp = g.Max(b => b.TimeStamp),
                        lastTimestamp = g.Min(b => b.lastTimestamp)
                }
                ).OrderBy(a => a.timestamp);


        
            Console.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(err,Formatting.Indented));
    }
}
```

Test here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am trying to understand it and will report back once I implemented it.